# Where can I get WirelessHART systems?

Tags: wireless

The only system I have found is from [DUST Networks](http://www.linear.com/products/wireless_sensor_networks) (aquired by Linear), but no other implementations. Is it possible to implement the architecture on other microcontrollers?
I want to program a microcontroller with HART and communication to my external sensors, and not buy a finished box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Hart Communication Foundation has a list of all registered HART members:

http://www.hartcommproduct.com/inventory2/index.php?action=listcat&search=search...&tec=2&cat=&mem=&x=24&y=15

Comment: The thing is I want to program the microcontroller my self, looking for the framework used in HART applications. I can not see how I will be able to monitor my sensors if I buy a finished enclosure, just functioning as a network and not communicating with external modules.

Comment: Look at the list again, a few of those are modems, adapters and gateways which you would ingtegrate with your own design

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at this page http://www.hartcomm.org/protocol/wihart/wireless_technology.html? You certainly can do it with any microcontroller with enough power to handle the crypto stuff. However, you always need the IEEE802.15 radios ...

Comment: Where do you find the actual framework to implement? Very good info tho :)

Comment: I'm not sure. Why don't you get in contact with the people at the Hart Communication Foundation?